# .htaccess in cakephp

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I do not want to use mod_rewrite on cakephp and I want to use cakePHP's pretty URLs. So I have removed all the .htaccess files

1. /.htaccess
2. /app/.htaccess
3. /app/webroot/.htaccess

and uncommentted this line on core.php

Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));

Noe the problem is...if I am putting controller and action in URL it is showing a 404 not found error.

http://www.mydomain.com/controller/action - showing not found

Can anyone help me out this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try either:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/controller/action

http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?controller/action
```